# how to get total duration, total passed and failed test case in serenity cucumber java

Tags: java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

i have an automation API and web written in java, serenity and cucumber. how can i get the value of total duration, passed and failed test case ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello are you asking about how to generate serenity report ?

If yes, install add this serenity maven plugin in your pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.plugin.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${serenity.plugin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-single-page-report</artifactId>
                    <version>${serenity.plugin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <reports>single-page-html</reports>
            </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

If you are using IntellijIdea in the plugins section you will have the plugin serenity:aggregate, run it.

You can also run the command `mvn serenity:aggregate` in the command line to get the full report and the summay report

Comment: You will need to set this in the properties section <serenity.plugin.version>3.9.0</serenity.plugin.version>

Answer (score 0):

You can get details of the total duration, count of passed and failed test cases, and many other details from the Serenity report.

Serenity report is available in target/site/index.html

When you open the report on the homepage you can find these details.

As already pointed out by others remember to add dependencies in pom.xml file.

PFB sample report screenshots

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSdbb.png)

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoXiC.png)